# Date format YYYY-MM-DD+11:00 convert in to YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, date, format

I Received excel data with following format
Date format YYYY-MM-DD+11:00 (Ex 2014-02-15+11:00 /2014-02-18+13:00)

Now I need to convert into this format
2014-02-18 HH:MM:SI

Please help me to do this

cheers

Comment: Is the current data formatted as a Date, or as General? If Date, you should be able to enter `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SI` as a custom format and then change the existing data to that format. If it's a "General" field, you may want to take a look at the `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` formulas in Excel. You'll need to do a little parsing, and you'll still need to create the custom format above.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick test. It's a little sloppy, but this formula will work. For the sake of argument, it assumes that the data you're trying to convert is in A1 of the current sheet, that it's all the same length, and that the format is "General":

```
=SUM(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10)),TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5)))
```

Wherever you use the above formula, change the format to the Custom Format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SI`. I'm not sure what you're looking for with `SI`. I'm taking that literally. That custom format will display the seconds value and then the letter `I`. If you're looking for a different value, like milliseconds, then you can look that up. But if the data you're converting *is* in a "General" format, when you convert it, it won't have seconds or milliseconds, anyway. Those will all get converted to 00s.